# Why is my crontab not working when I use local time in RedHat?

Tags: cron, redhat

I defined a `cron` job to refer to my local time but it is not working.

I have tried to define it using Universal time. It is working, but my question is why the `crontab` is not working on my local time.

See the definition details below.

Is there something that needs to be changed to make `crontab` use the local time?

```
[root@mykultestrhel04t hoho]# timedatectl

Local time: Mon 2019-08-26 14:33:22 +08 >> not working
Universal time: Mon 2019-08-26 06:33:22 UTC >> working
RTC time: Mon 2019-08-26 06:33:22
```

An example `crontab` entry would be

```
09 06 * * * /usr/bin/find /test/hoho -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The time refers to UTC, not my local time.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable. But there are some details that you should supply to make it answerable: 1) the `crontab` that works and the `crontab` that doesn't 2) the commands you used in both cases 3) an exact description of what you mean by "it doesn't work". Please edit the question and add that information.

Comment: i mean my crontab job run with UTC time not my local server time.

Comment: if i put in crontab follow my local time, it wont run the command, i want the command run refer to my local time, it possible?